# Ruby on Rails Casing: Why Use Caps Here?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, controller

Rails newbie question...

Consider the following code:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end
  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    @article.save
    redirect_to @article
[...]
```

I don't understand why the `A` in `Article.new` has to be capitalized. All other references to article(s) are lower-case. Why, in this context, is it different?

Comment: Ruby conventions: `MyClassName`, `MY_CONSTANT`, `my_method`, `my_local_variable`, `@my_instance_variable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because model `Article` is class. *class(s)* are *constants* in Ruby. You are creating an instance of the model(class) `Article` and then saving the instance into the DB.

In Ruby *class(s)* are constants, but *anonymous* class(s) or module(s) not needed always need to be a constants. You can assigned the anonymous class(s) to constants if you want.

[`Class::new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Class.html#method-c-new)

> Creates a new anonymous (unnamed) class with the given superclass (or Object if no parameter is given). *You can give a class a name by assigning the class object to a constant*.

Once, you assgined it to a *constant*, it is not now an *anonymous* class, because it has the name.

```
klass = Class.new
klass.name # => nil

Klass = klass
Klass.name # => "Klass"
```

Same stands for [`Module::new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Module.html#method-c-new).

As you are in Rails, you should check this out [`2.1 Naming Conventions`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#naming-conventions).

> By default, Active Record uses some naming conventions to find out how the mapping between models and database tables should be created. Rails will pluralize your class names to find the respective database table. So, for a class Book, you should have a database table called books........

Comment: Classes are usually constants, but they don't have to be constants. `a = Class.new` is fine.

Comment: @Arup Rakshit (great name!): Thanks. That answers my question perfectly.